# ERROR 404 MVC ASP.NET Application server error '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have a question about .Net MVC, because Visual Studio shows me the application server error in the following form?

> Server error in application '/'. The resource cannot be found.
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
> dependencies) may have been removed, renamed, or temporarily
> unavailable. Please review the URL below and make sure it is spelled
> correctly.
>
> Requested URL: / Register

```
<form action="Account/Registra" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="id" value="" placeholder="Id" required/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nombre" required/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="correo" value="" placeholder="Correo" required/>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="contrasena" value="" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="direccion" value="" placeholder="Direccion" required/>
    <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn" value="Registrar" />
</form>
```

And this one that has the same action text "controller / action" but does this work correctly for me.

```
<form action="Account/Validar" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="correo" value="" placeholder="Correo" required class="form-control"/>
    <input type="password"  name="contrasena" value="" placeholder="Contraseña" required class="form-control"/>
    <input type="submit"  name="btn" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-primary form-control"/>
</form>
```

They both have their respective existing methods and views. Any solution or opinion about this error?

```
        public ActionResult Registra()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registra(MUsuario usuario)
        {
            HttpClient _http = new HttpClient();
            _http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60467/");
            var request = _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Values",usuario).Result;
            if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Account");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Registro", "Account");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the controller actions?  Perhaps they explicitly use different HTTP methods?

Comment: You probably need to have a look at how you have set up your routing (at startup) and possibly post that here.

Comment: I have the default map route, above add my methods